# How easy is it to write code against a normal sql db using EF Code First 4.3 and then switch to azure?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Is the implementation of a Sql database different from an Azure SQL database? If I write my application using Sql now can I scale it later down the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, SQL Azure implements a subset of SQL Server’s features. SQL Azure automatically manages the servers for us. This training course will give you more details on how to migrate from SQL Server to SQL Azure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_MigratingDatabasestoSQLAzure. Please check it and see whether it helps.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. SQL Azure is running on top of SQL 2012 and contains most of the functionality. I have not used EF 4.3 but with NHibernate I have a large application that can run pretty painlessly on SQL Azure or a local SQL Server.